# Can I use PrevState to have my component hold the user input on refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the users input updating the state. And on `ComponentDidUpdate` I save the state to an endpoint. But when I click to another page or refresh the page the state and the input reset. How can I have the component hold the users input without using local storage or cacheing? Im just learning about `prevState` and `prevProps`. And Im wondering if I can use those to help my component hold the value without breaking anything any advice would be great here is my component that is holding the state:

PatientInfo.js

```
export default class PatientInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chiefComplaint: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCatalog();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(this.state.chiefComplaint !== ""){
      api.Encounters.updateChiefComplaint(
        {chiefComplaint: this.state.chiefComplaint},
        this.props.encounterID
      );
    }
  }

render() {
return (
      <div className="patient-info">
        <InfoEditWrapper
          data={intake.chiefComplaint}
          readOnly={true}
          onCancel={onCancelIntake("chiefComplaint")}
          onSave={onSaveIntake("chiefComplaint")}
        >
          <ChiefComplaint
            intake={intake}
            catalog={this.state.catalog}
            patient={this.props.patient || null}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ chiefComplaint: e})}
            value={this.state.chiefComplaint}
          />
        </InfoEditWrapper>
}
```

ChiefComplaint.js component:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  visitType: state.encounter.details.visitType
});

function ChiefComplaint(props) {


if (props.visitType === "nursing_home"){
    return(
<BlockSection title="Chief Complaint">
  <Input 
  style={{ height: "70px"}}
  type="textarea"
  disabled={false}
  name="chiefComplaint"
  onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
  value={props.value}
  />
</BlockSection>
    )
  }
```

Comment: use persiste state or localstorage

Comment: If you want the data to be removed after browser closing use session storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is entirely client-side, held within memory for the duration of the page. Once refreshed, React state is cleared. `prevState` only refers to the state of the **previous render**. It is given to you on the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook to help you determine whether or not state/props "actually" updated. By default, it does a shallow comparison of props and state to see if they had updated.

Short version: no, you can't use `prevState` to retain user input on refresh. Local/Session Storage is the way to go. Another solution, probably preferable solution, is to implement routing like [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/) and [lift your state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) so it can be shared across components for the duration of the client.

Comment: How lifting the state up could help to save data after refresh ?

Comment: Because instead of refreshing the page when routing, they could implement client-side routing which would allow them to maintain their client-side state.